# How to combine these custom fields as links in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I know there is probably a better way to do this. I have about 5 custom fields I need to combine

```
<?php 
$link = get_field('twitter');
if( $link ): ?>
    <a class="button" href="<?php echo esc_url( $link ); ?>"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a>
<?php endif; ?>


        <?php 
$link = get_field('linkedin');
if( $link ): ?>
    <a class="button" href="<?php echo esc_url( $link ); ?>"><i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this. You just have to add to the links array as many entries as you need. This way you can avoid repeating much code.

```
$links = [
    ["url" => get_field('twitter'), "icon" => "fa-twitter"],
    ["url" => get_field('linkedin'), "icon" => "fa-linkedin-in"]
];

foreach ($links as $link) {
    if ($link["url"]) {
        echo '<a class="button" href="' . esc_url($link["url"]) . '"><i class="fab ' . $link["icon"] . '"></i></a>';
    }
}
```

Adding phone number links will need a slightly different approach, as you shouldn't use the esc_url function which is intended for checking and cleaning urls

```
$phones = [
    ["number" => get_field('phone'), "icon" => "fa-phone"],
    ["number" => get_field('mobile'), "icon" => "fa-mobile"]
];

foreach ($phones as $phone) {
    if ($phone["number"]) {
        $onlyNumber = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $phone["number"]);
        echo '<a target="_blank" class="button-social-team" href="tel:' . $onlyNumber . '"><i class="fas ' . $phone["icon"] . '"></i></a>';
    }
}
```

The onlyNumber line is meant to sanitize the phone number by allowing only numbers in it, an removing everthing else.

Comment: One  more question if you can. I am trying to have it use the tel: on the phone but its adding in unwanted numbers 4887: when I just put tel without the colon it shows http: //tel: then the phone number which won't work. I need to strip the http and https out of the equation some how.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not very familiarized with wordpress. But I guess the problem is that the wordpress' "esc_url" function is adding http:// to the phone link. So I'll avoid using it for phone numbers. Just modified the answer, as you requested, to add the phone number case. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks yeah seems you have to write a function to disable http or something.

Comment: You can always use PHP's preg_replace function with a regular expression to explicitly remove the http:// or https:// part from a string. In this case, something like $url = preg_replace("(^https?://)", "", $url); will remove that from your url string.